# TableFilter: change to contains-sorting

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, tablefilter

I am trying to use [Coderazzi`s TableFilter](http://coderazzi.net/tablefilter/index.html) with my JTable, and for that i have to change the default search type. By default, TF finds strings beginning with given expression or complete matching strings (if instant filtering off).
However, I want TF to find all strings that contain given substring in any part.
As I understood the structure for now, to change sorting type I have to implement a new Parser for the TableFilterHeader and to change *RowFilter parseText* and use it in TableFilterHeader.

The test JTable class:

```
public class ZeTable extends JPanel{

public ZeTable(){
    String[] columns = {"colStr", "colInt", "colDbl", "colStr2"};

Object [] [] data = {
        {"Kathy", new Integer(5), new Double(7.5), "Ftps"},
        {"John", new Integer(3), new Double(17.8), "Rowing"},
        {"Sue", new Integer(23), new Double(8.17), "Knitting"},
        {"Jane", new Integer(20), new Double(9.16), "Speed reading"},
};

JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
this.add(scrollPane);
IParserModel myParser = new ParserModel();
TableFilterHeader filterHeader = new TableFilterHeader(table, myParser, AutoChoices.DISABLED);
filterHeader.setPosition(TableFilterHeader.Position.TOP);
IFilterEditor editor = filterHeader.getFilterEditor(0);
editor.setInstantFiltering(false); //with this only full match filters
IFilter f = editor.getFilter();

    }
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("ZeTable");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ZeTable newContentPane = new ZeTable();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });}

}
```

The Parser class:

```
public class MyParser implements IParser {    
    private IParser parser;

    public MyParser(IParser parser) {
        this.parser = parser;
    }
    @Override
    public RowFilter parseText(String expression) throws ParseException {
        RowFilter<Object, Object> containsFilter = new RowFilter<Object, Object>() {
            @Override
            public boolean include(RowFilter.Entry<? extends Object, ? extends Object> entry) {
                for (int i = entry.getValueCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (entry.getStringValue(i).contains(expression)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        return containsFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public InstantFilter parseInstantText(String expression) throws ParseException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String escape(String s) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String stripHtml(String s) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The idea was, *parseText* should return the filter i wanted, but TableFilter is still finding strings only if full match, so my Parser change did nothing. By now I`m totally confused and asking for any advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] so that a reader using this library can evaluate your approach.

Comment: Included the full code now